# Each visit is counted twice in Google Analytics after installing Fooman Google Analytics Plus

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, google-analytics

After installing the Fooman Google Analytics+ Magento plugin (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fooman-google-analytics.html) on Magento Community 1.8.1 each visit is counted twice. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fooman Google Analytics+ extension which can be found on magentocommerce is not compatible with Magento 1.8.1. After downloading and installing the extension from github (https://github.com/fooman/googleanalyticsplus) it works fine.